# How to make Vlookup index column dynamic?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, match, vlookup

How could I make `VLOOKUP()` work somewhat like this?

```
=VLOOKUP(Z10,Sheet1!A5:Z100,COLUMN(MATCH("ID",Sheet1!A5:5,0)),0)
```

...where the col index is obtained by matching the column header's with what's entered there.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should be:

```
=VLOOKUP(Z10, Sheet1!A5:Z100, MATCH("ID", Sheet1!A5:5, 0), 0)
```

where

```
=MATCH("ID", Sheet1!A5:5, 0)
```

match will output the number of column. lets say ID header is in E5. that's 5th column of range A5:5 so the output will be 5, therefore, vlookup will output the 5th column from A5:Z100 which is E column. summary: look for Z10 in A5:Z100 and if Z10 is found in A5:A100 range, output the matching column with header ID